Trying to fetch different data when and re-render the new data through a map function when a button is clicked
I am very new to react, and am trying to fetch data and map it onto the screen each time certain button is clicked:
  const fetchMessages = async (num) => {
      const response = await fetch([url] + num)
      const menuResponse = await response.json()
      console.log(menuResponse)
      setMenulist(menuResponse);
  }

The button click passes in a certain number appended to the end of a url (just called [url] for privacy), which then fetches array data from the server based on the number passed in. The correct menuResponse array is printed in the console. Lastly, it calls a useState function to change the menulist into the correct menuResponse array.
        <div className="menu">
          {useEffect(() => {
            menulist[section].map((menuItem) => {
              console.log("Inside Map: " + menuItem);
              <MenuCard mItem={menuItem}></MenuCard>
          })
          }, [menulist])}
        </div>

Inside this block, the correct menu items are being printed into the console, however nothing is mapped on the screen and I get the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". When I get rid of the surrounding useEffect the original render works, but any other button click results in the same error. Could anyone please help?

There are some mistakes on the component showed above.
First of all, menulist is a state and when menulist value is changing, it will cause a re-render, thus no useEffect is actually needed here.
Secondly, when using the .map method, you need to return something back.
Here is an example of how it should be structured (hope it helps)
export const MyComponent = () =>{
const [menuList, setMenuList] = useState([])

const fetchMessages = async (num) => {
    const response = await fetch('url' + num)
    const menuResponse = await response.json()
    console.log(menuResponse)
    setMenuList(menuResponse);
}

return <div>
    <button onClick={()=>fetchMessages(1)}>MyButton</button>
    <div className="menu">
        {menuList.map((menuItem) => {
            return <MenuCard mItem={menuItem}></MenuCard>
        })}
    </div>
</div>

}
